# Is it possible to cutover to a Solr new index in sub-second time?

Tags: apache-spark, indexing, solr, batch-processing

Something I have been thinking of for a while.  Let's say I have a solr implementation that has a very large index, and the index has to be rebuilt nightly due to new data imported daily.  Can have a job that indexes the new data into an index that is "off-line" then cut over to the new index when it has been fully indexed?  This would essentially mean my search index would only be searched and never updated in real time -- only when the new index was cut over.

Thanks in advance for any/all replies. 
-- MG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the two main possible scenarios :

**Single Solr Instance**

1. you create 2 cores : A, B
2. A online
3. re-index B (offline)
4. when ready you swap [1]

/solr/admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=A&other=B

N.B. you search client will point always to A

**SolrCloud architecture**

1. you create 2 collections : A, B
2. you assign an alias to A [2]:

*/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=online_search&collections=A*
N.B. you search client will access 'online_search' endpoints.

3. you re-index collection B
4. when ready you assign the alias to B[2]

*/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=online_search&collections=B*
 5. now collection A is offline

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-SWAP

[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-CREATEALIAS:CreateorModifyanAliasforaCollection

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to create two core.

- **SearchCore** - for Searching
- **IndexingCore** - for Indexing

When Indexing successfully done in **IndexingCore**. You need to **swap** IndexingCore with **SearchCore**.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=IndexingCore&other=SearchCore
```

After this SearchCore will point to IndexingCore data directory and vice versa. Then you can **unload** the IndexingCore So that it does not consume memory.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=IndexingCore
```

Comment: Interesting. What versions of SOLR support these actions? Thanks for,the great reply.

Comment: In theory I could have a bunch of different cores that get swapped in using this strategy, is that right?

Comment: And these cores don't have to be on the same solar instances, right? They just need to have the same schema?

Comment: @Griff Which Version of Solr are you using? But one thing is sure that these features are available in Solr 4, 5 or 6 and also I think cores have to be on one instance to perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

I would address this with [Aliases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-CREATEALIAS:CreateorModifyanAliasforaCollection) (assuming you are using Solrcloud):

1. say your collection is called 'current'
2. you create an alias a_current pointing to 'current'
3. your client code does not call 'current' collection itself, instead it just calls 'a_current'
4. whenever you need, you create a new collection with new data, say current_2
5. in one single operation, without downtime, using the same CREATEALIAS command as before, you point a_current to current_2

Answer (score 0):

If you're not talking about cores or collections on the same cluster or solr server, don't use Solr to distribute the requests (which would require you to keep a dedicated Solr server online to just use it as a sharding endpoint without doing anything useful).

Use a regular HTTP load balancer and point it to the active Solr server. Be sure to use proper warming queries on your Solr server with the fresh index before switching the load over to it (to avoid slow queries just when the server comes online). A load balancer might also be able to send queries to both nodes (but only return the response from your primary server) to let you dynamically warm the new server while still serving requests from the old one.